# HTML spaces without the underline

Tags: html, href

I have the following HTML code

```html
<div class="pingid-link">
  <a href="/assets/PingID/pingid-setup.html" class="box" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src="/assets/PingID/PingID.jpg" alt="PingID">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="">PingID Setup</span></a>

</div>
```

The problem for me is the underscore lines between the image and the text.  How can I remove the underscore link between the image and the text?

[image: stuff to fix]

Comment: It's all your non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`) causing it. Just remove those. And add a css `margin-right` on your image to create that space. e.g.: `a:link img {
margin-right: 0.5em;
}`

Answer (score 2):

By default, `a` elements have the `text-decoration: underline` property. Since you have an `img` and `white-space` in your link, you need to give your link a style using CSS/inline styling to change this. Then you can give the span itself an `underline` if you want the text to retain its underline.

```css
a{
  text-decoration: none;
}

span{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">test test test <span>link</span></a>
```

**Edit:** As some of the commenters have pointed out, this might not be answering your question sufficiently, and might be teaching you a bad practice.

To clarify, I am trying to demonstrate that there is an inherent property to the `a` element that causes all of its children to have an *text-decoration: underline* attribute.

In your specific case, I would recommend doing something like this:

```css
.logo {
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="pingid-link">
  <a href="/assets/PingID/pingid-setup.html" class="box" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img class="logo" src="/assets/PingID/PingID.jpg" alt="PingID"><span style="">PingID Setup</span></a>

</div>
```

Here, we remove your `&nbsp;` elements and then apply a `margin` property to the right side of your image to recreate the lost space. `Margin` in my example is a shorthand to allow you to set the `margin` property on any given side from top, right, bottom and left respectively.

Comment: The effect here is weird: the entire _test test test link_ sequence is clickable but only the 'link' portion has the underline - it's not very UX friendly.  Upvoted for the explanation about defaults

Comment: It's simpler to just remove the non-breaking spaces which are creating the underlined blank space. And then make a margin or padding around the image. Instead of removing all underlines that would affect all unrelated links too, and then having to re-create new underlines in a span.

Comment: @blurfus That was intentional to illustrate how the image was also being affected by the underline, and was just an example. In a real world scenario, you would probably put the image inside of a button with text and give the button `text-decoration: underline` because that would be better semantically.

Comment: Why not give OP a real-world scenario then?  Also, a button is not better semantically than a hyperlink (especially if the link is to take you to a different page) - the button would be better suited for actions on the same page (like form submit, for example) - it makes no sense to override the defaults of a button and call it semantically better (the button already has good, known defaults for acting like a button and not like a hyperlink)

Comment: Why give an answer that doesn't really simply solve the OP's problem (using `&nbsp;` problematically), but creates a new potential problem by removing link underlines globally, then tries to patch it up by adding a text-decoration `span`? He didn't ask "what are all the possible theoretical ways, good or bad, this underline could be removed."

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I revised my answer and I think the answer should be better suited to the question now. :)

Answer (score 0):

since it is the image is covered in a tag which will act as a link you can use this style: 
`a{ text-decoration: none;   }`

to remove the underline in your text.

Comment: I think OP only wants to remove underline in the white space, not the entire text of the hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

You can add a margin to the `<span>` and avoid the need to add (force) blank spaces between the image and the text.

See below:

```css
span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pingid-link">
  <a href="/assets/PingID/pingid-setup.html" class="box" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x25/aaa/fff" alt="PingID"><span>PingID Setup</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using non breaking space between image and span element.
remove this

```css
img{
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pingid-link">
  <a href="/assets/PingID/pingid-setup.html" class="box" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/1215/1215840.png?w=740&t=st=1660679446~exp=1660680046~hmac=28860ef42c9d54aa4989079dd44f65feb033eef70bb648ad2362d0f32e17a1ea" alt="PingID">
    <span class="undeScore"style="">PingID Setup</span></a>

</div>
```